# QT-creator: c++ application break after running several time

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am working on a Qt application which is used as client to send message to a tomcat server. After running the application for like four times to send or retrieve data back, the application breaks with error message

```
ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file** /usr/include/qt4/qtCore/qlist.h, line 282.
```

When I clicked on it I don't understand what it means. Does it have anything to do with memory allocation?

Comment: The class holding the list or the listpointer iteself is eventually pointing to a wrong address. As soon as the lists class-methods are called this will often make the app crash (depending on target of the pointer)

Answer (score 0):

You try to access an element from a QList that is empty, debug your code and see where you have that access.
In this [file](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/HEAD/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h) it looks that at line 282 the *first* member function is defined, so you can start with a search in your code to see where you call *first* and fix it (call first only if the list is not empty), but note that the *last*, *remove* and other member function might use that assert, and at that line number it might be a different member function with the version of Qt you are using, so check that too.